# Using Interface Builder tags

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm using interface builder's tag feature to access some UILabels I'm instantiating in a xib file. Since this a UITextViewCell I want to avoid superfluous method calls, but I want to do it right too. Thus when I do:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

I'm wondering if I should wrap it up like so:

```
if([[cell viewWithTag:1] isKindOfClass [UITableViewCell class]]) {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
}
```

Any discussion on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a lot of different objects of different classes that have subviews tagged '1' then this isn't necessary.

If you DO have a bunch of different objects (cells, say) that have different classes but all have subviews with a 1 tag, I'd reconsider your tagging scheme. Perhaps 101, 201, & 301, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Like August, I'd suggest making your tag numbers unique within that branch of your view hierarchy.

I'd also suggest that you set up an `enum` to enumerate your possible tag values so that your `viewWithTag:` method becomes more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I find the enum method works well, or just doing #define foo 1, #define bar 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You set tags in interface builder using command-1 in the attribute editor and look for 'tag' underneath the background setting.